# tool linux xsltproc tag defined in a xslt is not written in output xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm using linux xsltproc command to execute a xslt.
I have an issue . A tag defind in the xsltis not written in output xml

The xslt code is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ata="http://tmme.toyota.com/ata/exchange/1.1" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" exclude-result-prefixes="xsi xsl fo">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/ata:exchange">
        <ata:developement xmlns:ata="http://tmme.toyota.com/ata/exchange/1.1">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </ata:developement>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="dropdowns">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="coreAttributes">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="attributeGroups">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="templateAttributes">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="dynamicAttributes">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="dynamicAccessories">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="commonAttributes">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="specificAttributes">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="type">
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

input file

```
<ata:exchange xmlns:ata="http://tmme.toyota.com/ata/exchange/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <dropdowns>
        <dropdown reference="1021">
            <name>Balance weight</name>
            <choices>
                <choice reference="1078" default="false">
                    <values>
                        <value language="cs" country="CZ">test CZ</value>
                        <value language="nl" country="BE">test BE</value>
                    </values>
                </choice>
                <choice reference="1079" default="false">
                    <values>
                        <value language="cs" country="CZ">out CZ</value>
                        <value language="da" country="DK">out DK</value>
                    </values>
                </choice>
                <choice reference="1080" default="false">
                    <values>
                        <value language="cs" country="CZ">Podle  ETRTO (V2.03.1) (V2.03.2)</value>
                        <value language="da" country="DK">According to ETRTO (V2.03.1) (V2.03.2)</value>
                    </values>
                </choice>
            </choices>
        </dropdown>
    </dropdowns>
</ata:exchange>
```

output file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dropdowns xmlns:ata="http://tmme.toyota.com/ata/exchange/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<dropdown reference="1021">
<name>Balance weight</name>
<choices>
<choice reference="1078" default="false">
<values>
<value language="cs" country="CZ">test CZ</value>
<value language="nl" country="BE">test BE</value>
</values>
</choice>
<choice reference="1079" default="false">
<values>
<value language="cs" country="CZ">out CZ</value>
<value language="da" country="DK">out DK</value>

</values>
</choice>

<choice reference="1080" default="false">
<values>
<value language="cs" country="CZ">Podle  ETRTO (V2.03.1) (V2.03.2)</value>
<value language="da" country="DK">According to ETRTO (V2.03.1) (V2.03.2)</value>
</values>
</choice>
</choices>
</dropdown>
</dropdowns>
```

the output xml doesn't contain the main tag
<ata:developement xmlns:ata="http://tmme.toyota.com/ata/exchange/1.1">
which is defined in the xslt

I have that version of xsltproc on SUSE slis 12.
Using libxml 20907, libxslt 10132 and libexslt 820                                                                                                                                                                                                             xsltproc was compiled against libxml 20907, libxslt 10132 and libexslt 820                                                                                                                                                                                     libxslt 10132 was compiled against libxml 20907                                                                                                                                                                                                                libexslt 820 was compiled against libxml 20907

I call the command like

xsltproc file.xsl fileinput.xml -o fileoutput.xml

I receive
Warning : failed to load entity "-o"
unable to parse -o
exit code 6

If I try with xmlspy, the output is correct .

Can somebody help me?

Kind regards

Eric Koralewski

Comment: Please edit your question and add an example input.

Comment: Hi Michael,
I put an input file and an output file

Comment: The problem cannot be reproduced using your code: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bET2rY8

Comment: I made a test with Xmlspy, that works too. But the issue is with linux command xsltproc

Comment: FWIW, I have tested the above using xsltproc on macOS. Anyway, the problem is not in the code you posted.

Comment: I have that version of xsltproc on SUSE slis 12

Comment: I have a SUSE slis 12 linux version. I added the version details of xsltproc a at the end of the main message

Comment: I think you should retag your question and also add the code you have calling the transformation.

Comment: Please show your command line or application layer (Java, Python, etc.) call to `xsltproc`.

Comment: I call the command like 
xsltproc file.xsl fileinput.xml -o fileoutput.xml
I receive 
Warning : failed to load entity "-o"
unable to parse -o
exit code 6

but the output file is created but without the error indicated above

Comment: When `xsltproc` exits with an error code, then the output file is *probably* not created. Fix the command line so that does not throw warnings or errors. Your XSLT itself is unnecessarily repetitive, but technically it's working.

Comment: the output is created despite the exit code 6 but wrongly created

Comment: I changed order of the parameters and that works
now I put 
xsltproc -o fielout.xml filexsl.xsl fileinput.xml
previously I used
xsltproc filexslt.xsl fileinput.xml -o fileoutput.xml

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).